# Visual Studio 2013 Quick Watch (& Static Properties)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, static-members

In debugging step through, Visual Studio 2013 shows `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is:

1. false: When I hover mouse on `BitConverter` and see the value of `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` and
2. true: When I put it in a variable like `var x = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;`

I assume `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` should be already evaluated because I have called `GetBytes` on `BitConverter` so it's static constructor should be called at this point, right? What am I missing?

My code is this (I wanted to generate sequential `Guid`; `rest` is bytes of a `long` counter - at this version):

```
static Guid Id(long ticks, byte[] rest)
{
    var ticksBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ticks).PolishEndian();
    // var x = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian; // <- TESTED HERE
    int a = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { ticksBytes[4], ticksBytes[5], ticksBytes[6], ticksBytes[7] }.PolishEndian(), 0);
    short b = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { ticksBytes[2], ticksBytes[3] }.PolishEndian(), 0);
    short c = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { ticksBytes[0], ticksBytes[1] }.PolishEndian(), 0);

    return new Guid(a, b, c, rest.PolishEndian(true).ToArray());
}

static byte[] PolishEndian(this byte[] ba, bool reverse = false)
{
    var flag = reverse ? BitConverter.IsLittleEndian : !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;

    if (flag) return ba.Reverse().ToArray();

    return ba;
}
```

Comment: Note that in this case you are looking at a static field, not a static property which does change things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this case `IsLittleEndian` is actually a field and not a property.  That has an effect on how the EE is able to process the value.

I tried this out locally and this is the behavior I saw

First i stepped until the cursor hit the `var ticksBytes` line.  At that point I observed that `IsLittleEndian == false`.  This is actually expected at this point.   The EE does not always need to force a static constructor to run in order to read fields.  Hence it is just reading the value as is and because no other code for `BitConverter` has run the value is `false`

Immediately after stepping over that line I observe that `IsLittleEndian == true`.  The CLR ran the static constructor in order to execute the `GetBytes` method and hence that set the field.  The EE was then reading the set field.

Note that you can recreate this example with your own code.  For example

```
static class Test { 
  static readonly bool example;

  static Test() { 
    example = true;
  }

  internal static void Go() { 
    // example == true 
  }
}

class Program { 

  static void Main() {
    // Test.example == false;
    Test.Go();  
  }
}
```

Earlier I mentioned that the EE didn't always need to execute a static constructor in order to read fields.  One case where it often needs to is when reading static fields off of a generic type.  The storage for a static field of a generic type isn't created essentially until the CLR instantiates an instance of the type.  Hence in order to read a field off of a generic type which hasn't yet been used the EE will create an instance under the cover in order to force the CLR to read it.  For example

```
static class Test<T>
{
    static readonly bool example = false;

    static Test()
    {
        example = true;
    }
}
```

If you add this to your program and then evaluate the following in the watch window

```
Test<int>.example
```

you will find that the value is `true` clearly indicating the `cctor` ran